File with execute permissions still not running
I am trying to set up OpenVPN on my computer that is currently running Ubuntu and following these directions:
OpenVPN Setup
My problem is arising however when I try to run
# echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/openvpn.asc] https://packages.openvpn.net/openvpn3/debian DISTRIBUTION main" >>/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn3.list

I get this error:
computerName:~$ sudo echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/openvpn.asc] 
https://packages.openvpn.net/openvpn3/debian DISTRIBUTION main" >>/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn3.list
bash: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn3.list: Permission denied
computerName:~$ ls -l /etc/apt/keyrings
total 4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3165 Oct 25 15:58 openvpn.asc

As you can see the file has execute permission and I am running from root so I am not sure what else could be blocking my access to the file, any help would be greatly appreciated

Output redirection is done in your original shell, not in the process executed by sudo, so it uses your permissions.
